# counting all possible realizations of k subsets of a set $U$ such that no one is a subset of another and the union of these $k$ subsets is $U$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $U=\{1,2,...,N\}$, and $k$ non-empty subsets $U_i\subset U$, such that:

i) none of these k subsets is a subset of another;

ii) $\bigcup_{i=1}^k U_i=U$.

Given any $k$, what is the total number of possible realizations of such $k$ subsets?

When $k = 1$ or $2$, it appears easy to calculate the total number of possible realizations. **How about $k\geq 3$? Does anyone have any idea?**

Note that the $k$ is upper bounded by ($N$ choose $floor(N/2)$), as given by this relevant post:

[Find maximal number of subsets of the set $U$ such that no one is a subset of another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129267/find-maximal-number-of-subsets-of-the-set-u-such-that-no-one-is-a-subset-of-an)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For $N=k=2$ there are two solutions, right? $U_1=\{1\},U_2=\{2\}$ and $U_1=\{2\},U_2=\{1\}$  count as two different solutions? Otherwise we have to divide by $2!$.

Comment: For N=k=2, we can count these two solutions as one.

Comment: For k=3, how do you get this formula? Let's say N=3, and k=3, your formula leads to 12. However, by computer search, there are only two solutions: {1},{2},{3}; {1,2},{1,3},{2,3}.

Comment: Note that @bof's formula was posted before you clarified that the permutations of subsets are *not* distinct solutions, and $12 = 2 \cdot 3!$ if we count such permutations as distinct solutions.

Comment: Now let's consider $N=4$ and $k=3$. The formula leads to $48$. But by computer search, there are $56$ solutions (will check this again).

Comment: My **corrected** formula for $k=3$ is $$\frac{7^N-6\cdot5^N+6\cdot4^N+3\cdot3^N-6\cdot2^N+2}{3!}.$$ For $N=3,\ 4,\ 5,\ 6$ it produces the values $2,\ 56,\ 790,\ 8380.$ These numbers and the formula are in agreement with OEIS sequence [A056046](http://oeis.org/A056046), "Number of $3$-antichain covers of a labeled $n$-set".

Comment: I worked out the formula from scratch (**finally** getting it right after several tries) using the inclusion-exclusion formula. You could call this reinventing the wheel. The easy way would have been to use the numbers 2, 56, 790, 8380 from your computer program and search the oeis.org database for the sequence.

Comment: @bof  Thank you very much for helping me out.