# proof verification - A. Shen, A set contains $2n$ elements, select $k$ subsets that none is a subset of others

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> Problem 14. A set U contains $2n$ elements. We select $k$ subsets of
>   $U$ in such a way that none of them is a subset of another one. What
>   is the maximum possible value of $k$? (Hint: Maximal $k$ is achieved
>   when all subsets have $n$ elements. Indeed, imagine the following
>   process: We start with an empty set and add random elements one by one
>   until we get $U$. At most one selected set can appear during this
>   process. On the other hand, the expected number of selected sets that
>   appear during this process can be computed using the linearity of
>   expectation. Take into account that the probability to come across
>   some set $Z \subset U$ is minimal when $Z$ contains n elements, since
>   all the sets of a given size are equiprobable.)

There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129267/find-maximal-number-of-subsets-of-the-set-u-such-that-no-one-is-a-subset-of-an) was already asked before, but I want to prove this following the hint of the author.

With some help from translators and another hint from a [Russian site](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/95884/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-2n-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?answer_sort=votes), I have a vague understanding about the problem, but I'm not sure it's correct, and some of my explanation I feel like not clear enough. So my question is:

1) Is it correct?

2) Could you provide a proof based on the hint of the book or refine my proof (the case it's correct)?

---

Let $K$ is the system of subsets of $U$, such that none of them is a subset of another one.

By adding random elements one by one to an empty set until we get $U$, then we have $2n!$ possible outcomes.

Consider the probability that a set of $K$ appear in the process of selecting elements of $U$, that is, if $M\in K$, all of the first $m=\left|M\right|$ elements of selecting process will be elements of $M$.

Then, for each process, at most only one $M$ will be recognized (if not, more than 1 sets are recognized, there's set of $K$, which $M$ be its subset). Let $\xi_{M}$, $M\in K$ be Bernoulli random variables with, $P\left\{ \xi_{M}=1\right\} =p=\dfrac{1}{2n!}$, the probability of appearance of set M in each process, $P\left\{ \xi_{M}=0\right\} =1-p$.

Let $S_{i}$ is the result of $i$-th selecting process, $S_{i}=\xi_{M_{1}}+\cdots+\xi_{M_{i}}$. Because, at some selection process, no $M$ could be select, so $\mathrm{E}S_{2n!}\leq1$.

Let $t_{m}$ the number of sets with the same cardinality $m$, and $\sum t_{m}=k$:
$$\mathrm{E}S_{2n!}= \sum m!\left(2n-m\right)!\cdot t_{m}\cdot p\\ = \sum\binom{2n}{m_{i}}^{-1}t_{m}$$

But, for all $m$, $\dbinom{2n}{n}^{-1}\leq\dbinom{2n}{m_{i}}^{-1}$, and for the case all the set of $K$ have $n$ elements, then each of process of selecting elements we could always select a set of $K$, that is $\mathrm{E}S_{2n!}=1$. We have:
$$\sum\binom{2n}{m_{i}}^{-1}t_{m} \leq\sum\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}t_{n}\\
\sum t_{m} \leq\sum t_{n}\\ k \leq \sum t_{n}$$
That is the number $k$ attains maximum when all the set of $K$ have $n$ elements.

Comment: See the LYM inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality