# Maximum number of subsets of 2n-element set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set and $|S| = 2n$. $S$ has $k$ subsets such that none of them is a subset of the other. What is the maximum value of $k$?

I think it's $\binom{2n}{n}$, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Take $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, 2n\}$. Isn't the answer to your question simply $S_1 = \{1\}, S_2 = \{2\}, \ldots, S_{2n} = \{2n\}$, giving $2n$ such subsets? (Easily proven via inclusion-exclusion)

Comment: @GarethMa fixed the problem statement.

Comment: And it is a dup! [Find maximal number of subsets of the set $U$ such that no one is a subset of another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129267/find-maximal-number-of-subsets-of-the-set-u-such-that-no-one-is-a-subset-of-an)

Comment: @GarethMa I guess so, thanks!

Comment: Also just to help, the theorem is called Sperner's Theorem

Comment: @C-RAM OP edited his question, check edit history.